# How to create date range row from start date and a number in Prestodb SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I have this kind of table in `prestodb` which has a `start_date` field and a incremental counter.

```
| num | start_date | val |
|-----|------------|-----|
| 2   | 2017-03-01 | 100 |
| 3   | 2017-03-05 | 233 |
```

How can I convert it into this kind of table using `presto` `sql`?

```
| date       | val |
|------------|-----|
| 2017-03-01 | 100 |
| 2017-03-02 | 100 |
| 2017-03-05 | 233 |
| 2017-03-06 | 233 |
| 2017-03-07 | 233 |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  date_add ('day',s.n,t.start_date) as date
       ,t.val 

from    mytable t 
        cross join unnest(sequence(0,num-1)) s (n)
;
```

---

```
    date    | val
------------+-----
 2017-03-01 | 100
 2017-03-02 | 100
 2017-03-05 | 233
 2017-03-06 | 233
 2017-03-07 | 233
```

Comment: Thanks! However, it should be noted that it would only work only presto version 0.157 and up (because the sequence function).

Comment: Actually `sequence` was added in version 0.147 https://prestodb.io/docs/current/release/release-0.147.html P.s. don't confuse the 0.174 in `Presto 0.174 Documentation` with 0.147 in `11.32. Release 0.147` :-)

Answer (score -3):

Try this for `Sql Server`

```
Declare @s_id int = 1
;WITH dates AS 
(
    SELECT start_date as Date,@s_id as times,num as value,val
    from  @t 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,[Date]),times+1 as times,value,val
    FROM dates 
    WHERE times  < value
)

select Date,val from dates
order by val,date
```

Please note that the test table for this statement can be created by using...

```
declare @t ( num int,start_date date,val int)
insert into @t values (2,'2017-03-01',100)
insert into @t values (3,'2017-03-05',233)
```

Please replace `@t` in the main statement with the name of your table when testing the main statement against your table.

The following image shows the results of running the main statement against the test table...

[image]